# If terms of $\left\langle Tu,w\right\rangle$ are of the form $\left\langle Tv,v\right\rangle$, then $\left\langle Tu,w\right\rangle=0$. Why?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

In order to prove following theory, my textbook gives reasoning that $\left\langle Tu,w\right\rangle =0, \forall u,w$ implies $T=0$.
But I am unable to understand where is the fact used in this proof, that it is strictly a complex inner product space (not real), because it is false for real inner product space.

> Over $\mathbb{C}$, $T v$ is orthogonal to $v$ for all $v$ only for the $0$ operator.
>
> We have $\left\langle Tu,w\right\rangle=\frac{\left\langle T(u+w),u+w\right\rangle-\left\langle T(u-w),u-w\right\rangle}{4}+i\frac{\left\langle T(u+iw),u+iw\right\rangle-\left\langle T(u-iw),u-iw\right\rangle}{4}.$
>
> Each term on the RHS are of the form $\left\langle Tv,v\right\rangle$. Thus our hypothesis implies that $\left\langle Tu,w\right\rangle=0$, $\forall u,v\in V$. This implies that $T=0$ (taking $w=Tu$).

But real space is a subspace of a complex space. So, the proof should be valid for real space as well, which is not true?

Comment: The formula of  $\langle Tu, w \rangle$ is valid only in the complex case. In the real case you cannot prove that $\langle Tu, w \rangle$=0

Comment: You cannot decompose $\langle Tu,w\rangle$ as you did if $V$ would be a real vector space

Comment: I give you a second approach, more logical than algebraic. Say $V$ is a complex space, while $W$ is the "real subset" which is a "somehow real subspace of $V$" (whatever it means). Here the hypothesis is that $\forall v \in V$ something holds, where $V$ is a complex space. This hypothesis is strictly stronger than assuming that $\forall v \in W$ something holds. You have more vectors, more scalars, more constraints. Hence you can prove more things.

Answer (score 0):

In that proof, multiplication by $i$ is used. Therefore, the proof makes no sense in a real vector space.

On the other hand, your sentence “But real space is a subspace of a complex space.” is strange. Are you saying that every real vector space is a subspace of a complex vector space? What happens is that, for every real vector space $V$, there is a complex vector space such that $V$ is isomorphic to a real vector subspace of $W$. But that's a quite heavy approach for this problem.

Comment: Thanks. Because real numbers are a type of complex numbers with coefficients of $i$ as $0$s, why is real vector space not a subspace of complex vector space?

Comment: Let $V$ be a real vector space. Then, if $\lambda\in\Bbb R$ and $v\in V$, $\lambda v\in V$. But it is not automatically true that $\lambda v$ has some meaning if $\lambda\in\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R$.